# Is there a curve for which the area underneath between n and n+1 is exactly double the area underneath the curve between n+1 and n+2?

Tags: integration, curves

For example:
$$\int_x^{x+1} f(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2^x}$$
So for x = 0, the integral would be from 0 to 1 and would return 1.
For x = 1, the integral would be from 1 to 2 and would return 0.5 . And so on...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\int_\color{red}n^\color{red}{n+1}$?  Do you require $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: Why not $2^{-\lfloor x \rfloor}$?

Comment: Such a function, if continuous, would have to satisfy $f(x)-f(x+1) = \frac{\ln 2}{2^x}$.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution:

First off apply the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}\int_{x}^{x+1}{\rm d}z~f(z) = f(x+1) - f(x)
$$

therefore, the function $f$ should satisfy

$$
f(x+1) - f(x) = -\frac{\ln 2}{2^x} \tag{1}
$$

A [solution for this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5Bf%5Bn%2B1%5D-f%5Bn%5D%3D%3D-Log%5B2%5D%2F2%5En%2Cf%5Bn%5D%2Cn%5D) is

$$
f(x) = \ln 4 - 2^{1-x}(2^x - 1)\ln 2 \tag{2}
$$

The term $\ln 4$ is actually arbitrary, I just selected that number to keep $f(x) > 0$